# JCo generic handler registration for SAP FM

Tags: java, abap, jco, sapjco3

How to register handler in SAP JCo, so that it listens to all remote enabled SAP Function Modules, that are called in SAP with the 'Destination' parameter as the JCo Server?

I know, that we can register a handler for specific functions using this:

```
JCoServerFunctionHandler abapcallHandler = new AbapCallHandler();
DefaultServerHandlerFactory.FunctionHandlerFactory factory = new DefaultServerHandlerFactory.FunctionHandlerFactory();
factory.registerHandler(TabFun.getString("FUNCTION_NAME"), abapcallHandler);
server.setCallHandlerFactory(factory);
```

But how to create a generic handler, that will work dynamically for all functions, not only this explicit declared using "registerHandler" method?

Comment: Probably i found solution. We can just use method `registerGenericHandler()`instead of `registerHandler()`. So for example this way: 

`JCoServerFunctionHandler abapcallHandler = new AbapCallHandler();

DefaultServerHandlerFactory.FunctionHandlerFactory factory = new DefaultServerHandlerFactory.FunctionHandlerFactory();

factory.registerGenericHandler(abapcallHandler);

server.setCallHandlerFactory(factory);
`